# $\sin3x-\sin2x-\sin x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

I have issue solving this equation.
So I wrote $$\sin3x= 3\sin x-4\sin^3x$$ and $$\sin2x = 2\sin x\cos x$$
So we have $$3\sin x-4\sin^3x-(2\sin x\cos x)-\sin x = 0$$
But now I have $$\sin x$$ and $$\cos x$$ as unknown, and I don't know how to finish this.

Comment: Hint:Use $sin3x+sinx=sin(2x+x)+sin(2x-x)=2sinxcosx$.

Comment: Oh, That can work, thank you :)

Comment: Notice that $\sin x$ appears to an odd power in every term. Either $\sin x =0$ or you can divide through. Now you have $\sin x$ to an even power in every term ie an even function, which you should be able to express in terms of $\cos x$ using $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$, and this gives you a quadratic, which I am sure you can solve.

Comment: @MarkBennet so you mean dividing everything with $sinx$? So

Comment: $$3-4sin^2x-2cos-1=0$$?

Comment: Ah yes, that seems like the best option, thank you :)

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 4):

Hint: You can rearrange what you have to get
$$\sin x(1-\cos x)-2\sin^3 x=0\,.$$
So either $\sin x = 0$ or $1-\cos x-2\sin^2x=0$.

For the second case, use the fact that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: $x=k\pi$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$ also makes sine vanish (i.e. not just $x=0$).

Comment: Yes: I wrote $\sin x = 0$, which has solution $x=k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I just saw $x=0$ for some reason.

Comment: But $$sinx(1−cosx)−2sin3x=0.$$ does not equal $$3sinx−4sin3x−(2sinxcosx)−sinx=0$$

Comment: Assuming by $\sin3x$ you mean $\sin^3x$, then they are the same: combine together $3\sin x$ and $-\sin x$ to get $2\sin x-4\sin^3x-2\sin x\cos x=0$. Divide everything by $2$ to get $\sin x - 2\sin^3x-\sin x\cos x=0$. This is the same as $\sin x(1-\cos x)-2\sin^3x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sin { 3x-\sin { 2x } -\sin { x } =0 } \\ \left( \sin { 3x-\sin { x }  }  \right) -\sin { 2x } =0\\ 2\sin { \frac { 3x-x }{ 2 } \cos { \frac { 3x+x }{ 2 }  } -\sin { 2x }  } =0\\ 2\sin { x\cos { 2x-2\sin { x\cos { x }  } =0 }  } \\ \sin { x } \left( \cos { 2x-\cos { x }  }  \right) =0\\ \sin { x } =0,\cos { 2x-\cos { x } =0 } \Rightarrow 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ x } -\cos { x } -1=0\\ $$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

it can be factorized into
$$-8\cos(x/2)\sin(x/2)^3(1+2\cos(x))=0$$

Answer (score 0):

As the arcs are in *arithmetic progression*, rewrite the equation as
\begin{align}
\sin(2x+x)-\sin 2x -\sin(2x-x)&=2\sin x\cos 2x-\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos 2x-2\sin x\cos x \\
&=2\sin x(\cos2x-\cos x)
\end{align}
So one has to solve:

- $\sin x=\iff x\equiv 0\mod\pi$.
- $\cos 2x=\cos x \iff 2x\equiv\pm x\mod 2\pi\iff\begin{cases}x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\quad\text{(included in  the solutions of the previous equation)}\\
  3x\equiv 0\mod2\pi\iff x\equiv 0\mod\frac{2\pi}3\quad\text{(contains the previous solutions)}\end{cases}$